# Swift UIImage extension

Tags: ios, swift, enums, swift2, init

I am trying to make my code safer using an enum and a convenience initializer when dealing with UIImage and the asset catalog. My code is below:

```
import UIKit

extension UIImage {
    enum AssetIdentifier: String {
        case Search = "Search"
        case Menu = "Menu"
    }

    convenience init(assetIdentifier: AssetIdentifier) {
        self.init(named: AssetIdentifier.RawValue)
    }
}
```

Currently I am getting this error:

> 'Cannot invoke 'UIImage.init' with an argument of type '(named: RawValue.Type)'

Comment: Use lowerCamelCase for enum case names from Swift 3 onwards.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are 2 problems:

### 1. Failable init

In your `convenience initializer` you are calling a `failable initializer`. So how can you guarantee that an instance of `UIImage` is always created when you are relying on a `failable initializer` that, by definition, does not guarantee that?
You can fix this by using the magic `!` when you call the `failable init`.

### 2. Referencing the param you received

When you call `self.init` you are not passing the param received in your init. You are instead referencing the enum definition. To fix this replace this

```
self.init(named: AssetIdentifier.RawValue)
```

with this

```
self.init(named: assetIdentifier.rawValue)
```

### Wrap up

This is the result

```
extension UIImage {
    enum AssetIdentifier: String {
        case Search = "Search"
        case Menu = "Menu"
    }
    convenience init(assetIdentifier: AssetIdentifier) {
        self.init(named: assetIdentifier.rawValue)!
    }
}
```

### Testing

```
UIImage(assetIdentifier: .Search)
```

Comment: Thanks man yeah I just figured it out right before I refreshed the page. Its actually better to not make this init an optional value because you know your enum values are good.

Comment: @CodyWeaver: please don't forget to accept the answer if you think it is correct.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code. I have tested it.

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

enum AssetIdentifier: String {
    case Search = "Search"
    case Menu = "Menu"
}
extension UIImage {
    convenience init?(assetIdentifier: AssetIdentifier) {
        self.init(named: assetIdentifier.rawValue)
    }
}


class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var imageview: UIImageView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        imageview.image = UIImage(assetIdentifier: AssetIdentifier.Menu)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```